# Enumeration: Creating several enums of same "type" with different values?

Tags: java, enums, enumeration

I am currently struggling with my implementation of an enum type.

I'd like to have an enum "Day" with the specific types "Monday", "Tuesday", ... "Sunday".

Now I want to have an object "task" on each of the days and be able to have several "Mondays" or several "Sundays" containing different tasks.

```
public enum Day{
        MONDAY(0),
        TUESDAY(1),
        WEDNESDAY(2),
        THURSDAY(3),
        FRIDAY(4);
        SATURDAY(5);
        SUNDAY(6);

        /* Number of day */
        int dayNumber;
        /* menus of the day*/
         Task task;

        /*
         * Initializes the day with given number
         */
        private Day(int dayNumber) {
            this.dayNumber = dayNumber;
            this.task = new Task();
        }


        public Task getTask () {
            return task;
        }

        public void setTask() {
            this.task = task;
        }
    }
```

How do I create several Mondays, Tuesdays ... and so on and set different tasks for them? In my implementation I always end up with several Day's containing the same tasks. For example I create

```
Day day1 = Day.MONDAY;
Day day2 = Day.MONDAY;
Day day3 = Day.MONDAY;

day1.setTask(new Task(x));
day2.setTask(new Task(y));
day3.setTask(new Task(z));
```

Now the implementation above in my program results in all three days (day1, day2 and day3) containing the task initialized with "z" and I dont quite understand why. How do i manage to initialize days of the same type ("Day.MONDAY" in this example) with different values?

Comment: Enums are singletons.  There's only one `MONDAY` in the entire system, so your implementation just uses whatever was set most recently.  `day1`, `day2` and `day3` are all references to the same object.

Comment: Enums are implicitly -> public static final

Comment: You don't, you make a non-enum class that contains the correct enum value and its associated data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coupling the `Task` in the `Day` enum should be very probably avoided.
Having a mutable state is able in an enum but it will make it less readable and less reusable.
You should probably redesign the responsibilities between the `Task` and the `Day`.

You have broadly two possibilities.

**Decoupled Day and Task**

Create a class that composes a `Task` and a `Day` enum :

```
public class DayTask{

     private Day day;
     private Task task;
    ....
}
```

You could so write :

```
DayTask oneMondayTask = new DayTask(Day.MONDAY, new Task(...));
DayTask anotherMondayTask = new DayTask(Day.MONDAY, new Task(...));
```

Here the coupling between `Day` and `Task` is located only in the class that composes them.
Advantage : both `Day` and `Task` may be used alone.
Drawback : more code and structure to manipulate.

**Coupled Day to Task**

Here `Task` depends on a `Day`.
Advantage : less code and structure to manipulate.
Drawback : If `Task` doesn't require a `Day` in anycase, it gives more responsibilities/complexities than required in `Task`.

```
public class Task{

     private Day day;
    ....
}
```

You could so write :

```
Task oneMondayTask = new Task(Day.MONDAY);
Task anotherMondayTask = new Task(Day.MONDAY);
```

Answer (score 2):

Building on Jim's comment, I think he has the right of it.  What you probably want to do is make an object that can bind `Day` types to `Task`s.

```
class Binding {
  Map<Day,List<Task>> bindings = new HashMap<>();

  public void add( Day day, Task task ) {
    List<Task> tasks = bindings.get( day );
    if( tasks == null ) {
       tasks = new ArrayList<>();
       bindings.put( day, tasks );
    }
    tasks.add( task );
  }
}
```

Code is untested.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create several instances of an enum literal.

Enum instances are created by the the Java runtime and they are **singleton** objects.

This means that there will be only one `MONDAY` object. Period.

You will need to redesign your code by either changing the direction of your composition (make a `Task` know the day it's due), or by using other `Date` or `DateTime` classes.

Answer (score 0):

All 3 variables `day1`, `day2`, and `day3` refer to the *same* enum object, so when you call `setTask`, the changes show up through all 3 variables.

If you need different Mondays, then an enum is not the proper solution.  Create a `Day` class with different Monday instances.

If you need multiple tasks on the same day, then have a `List<Task>` instead of one `Task` in the enum definition, along with an implementation that adds `Task`s to the list.